# What kind of block format is the Desfire authentication message?

Tags: rfid, mifare

After selection of the card and RATS, i want to start the authentication.

In the mifare documentation is described that an  0A 00 should be sent. This data is supposed to be ISO14443-4. I have to frame it to fit ISO14443-3.

The Block format goes like that

**PCB|CID|INF|EDC**

In the PCB I am supposed to say if it is an I-block, R-block or S-block.

I saw an example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319321/how-can-i-do-native-authentication-in-desfire-ev1) where he sent something like that:

90 0A 00 00 01 00 00

Where is it documented this frame, it looks like none of the blocks described in ISO14443-4

Answer (score 3):

- The Block format PCB|CID|INF|EDC with I-block, R-block or S-block you described is actually ISO 7816-3 T=1 frame (not ISO 14443 frame, not ISO 7816-4 APDU). This is low-level ISO 7816 that implemented in driver level.
- The thread you mentioned uses 7816 APDU.
- 1st "to card" is actually 7816 APDU: CLA=90 **INS=0A** P1=00 P2=00 LC=01 *Data=00* Le=00
- 2nd "to card" is another APDU: CLA=90 **INS=AF** P1=00 P2=00 Lc=10 *Data=43 9D 17 8E 9A 5F BA 70 8D 23 57 10 C9 32 D5 17* Le=00.
- Depending on the version of Mifare DESFire, you can use native, native-wrapped or ISO 7816-4 command set styles.
- 7816 wraps Mifare native command as follow:
  90 **[mifare native ins]** 00 00 Lc [data] 00
- From the 2 commands above, native commands are 0x0A (Authenticate) & 0xAF (More data).
- You can't get the mifare native command set documentation freely. You need to sign an NDA. However, take a look at this doc to see learn more: http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11004.pdf
- Another resource: http://ridrix.wordpress.com/2009/09/19/mifare-desfire-communication-example/

Answer (score 2):

This is not a ISO 14443 frame; it is an ISO 7816-4 APDU.